# Is it necessary to have a model for every table?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, models, cakephp-3.0

I have some confusion regarding ORMs and more specifically with CakePHP. I have been using CakePHP for a while now and have found that in many respects it is very powerful, i.e. retrieval from databases using models.

I have the following tables:

```
Stores:
 id 
 store_name

Products:
 id
 product_name

Product_variants:
 id
 product_variant_id

product_to_stores
 store_id
 product_variant_id
```

Do I have to have a model for every table?

Comment: if you feel the answer below replied to your question, please mark it as 'Accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4):

The [CakePHP 3.x Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#create-an-article-model) mentions the following:

> *CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot
>   find a corresponding file in src/Model/Table.*

The same applies to entities, as described in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-entity-classes):

> *If you don’t define an entity class CakePHP will use the basic Entity class*.

Which means you can basically get started without writing a single class (provided you have followed conventions).

Just implement those model files that are required for your application to work, and put in them things such as associations, validation rules, custom methods, etc.

Again, it is important that you follow [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html). The more you adhere to conventions, the less configuration you will need.

On the question of whether you need *productvariants_stores* as a separate table, the answer is no if you set up your data model as follows:

[image]

You could then fetch the *productvariants* that are linked to *stores* by setting up the right relationships at the ORM level.

Comment: Hmm i got your point sir but what about saving an entity? I mean that in the above example i have a products variants table that has a one to one relation with store_to_variant do i need that model also separately to save data in that table even though this table contains only entities... And moreover this table seems to be totally dependent on other two entities. And if i put it simply i simply want to know do i need to consider variant_to_stores as a separate entity

Comment: Edited the question to reply to your comment.